# readAsArrayBuffer returning empty array (trying to convert video to blob and upload it)

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, ionic-framework, arraybuffer

I´m trying to upload a video using Ionic / Capacitor / React.

For this, I´m using the cordova-video-capture-plus plugin.

I´m getting stuck when I try to readAsArrayBuffer. For some reason it always comes back empty, below my code:

```
const doMediaCapture = async () => {
let options: VideoCapturePlusOptions = { limit: 1, duration: 30 };
let capture:any = await VideoCapturePlus.captureVideo(options);
let media = capture[0] as MediaFile;
// works on android....
let resolvedPath: DirectoryEntry;
let path = media.fullPath.substring(0, media.fullPath.lastIndexOf("/"));
if (Capacitor.getPlatform() === "ios") {
  console.log("ios")
  resolvedPath = await File.resolveDirectoryUrl("file://" + path);
} else {
  console.log("android")
  resolvedPath = await File.resolveDirectoryUrl(path);
}

console.log(media)
console.log(resolvedPath)
 File.readAsArrayBuffer(resolvedPath.nativeURL, media.name).then(
  (buffer: any) => {
    console.log(buffer)
    // get the buffer and make a blob to be saved
    let videoBlob: Blob = new Blob([buffer], {
      type: media.type,
    });
    let url = window.URL.createObjectURL(videoBlob);
    
    console.log(videoBlob)
    let { jobId } = apartments[+id!];
    if (videoBlob instanceof Blob) {
      console.log("processing as File");
      let fName = `${new Date().getTime()}`;

      if (videoBlob instanceof Blob) {
        if (videoBlob.type.split("/")[1] === "quicktime") {
          fName = fName + ".mov";
        } else {
          fName = fName + "." + videoBlob.type.split("/")[1];
        }
      }
      let ref = "videos/" + fName
      uploadVideo(jobId, videoBlob, ref)
    } else {
      console.log("processing as DataAsDataUrl");
      let v = videoBlob as DataAsDataUrl;
      let fName = `${new Date().getTime()}.${v.format}`;
      let ref = "images/" + fName
      uploadVideo(jobId, videoBlob, ref)
    }
  },
  (error:any) => console.log(error)
);
```

};

I get the following output which is an empty array, hence if I try to upload it it doesn´t upload anything:

[image]

How can I get that video file to be converted into a blob to upload?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to stop using the video-capture-plus plugin as it seems to have compatibility issues with different phones.
I went onto using the native plugin media-capture and it´s method MediaCapture.captureVideo()

Install the following plugin:
"@ionic-native/media-capture": "^5.24.0"
And its Cordova counterpart:
"cordova-plugin-media-capture": "^3.0.3",

Answer (score 1):

requestLegacyExternalStorage - is this set properly in the AndroidManifest? https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/modern-user-storage-on-android-e9469e8624f9